# c# Substring sendkeys

Tags: c#, serial-port, substring, sendkeys

I've got an **RFID-Reader** and want to Read the Data received at the serial port. This works fine as long as I don't use Substring.

When I use Substring I get an error Message with the second input from the COM-Port.

How can I get this to work? 
Does *SendKeys* only send "Keystrokes" or does it send a String?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SerialToKeyboard.Control
{
class ComToKey : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SerialPort _port;

    public ComToKey(SerialPort port)
    {
        _port = port;
        _port.DataReceived += PortOnDataReceived;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event thrown whenever the serial port received data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (_port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // PostKeys
            var original = _port.ReadExisting();
            original = original.Substring(0, 11);
            // Reformat string to fit SendKeys()
            var reformattedString = DefaultFormatter.Reformat(original);
            try
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait(reformattedString);
            }
            // Handle exception caused if keys are sent to an application
            // not handling keys
            catch(InvalidOperationException)    
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
            _port.Open();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_port.IsOpen)
            _port.Close();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_port.IsOpen)
            _port.Close();
        _port.DataReceived -= PortOnDataReceived;
        _port.Dispose();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: what's the error and on which line?

Comment: The Error Log from Windows: Ereignistyp: Fehler
Ereignisquelle: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Ereigniskategorie: Keine
Ereigniskennung: 5000
Datum:  05.08.2015
Zeit:  15:51:10
Benutzer:  Nicht zutreffend
Computer: MFT980-NR3
Beschreibung:
EventType clr20r3, P1 serialtokeyboard.exe, P2 0.1.2.0, P3 55c213c4, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889dc80, P7 15c, P8 1f, P9 system.argumentoutofrange, P10 NIL.     There is no Error while Debugging. Can't test on the computer where i am programming, because the RFID-Reader/Serial Port Driver doesn't work with Win 8.1